# Finding Dependencies of a System

Tags: common-lisp

How do I go about finding the complete dependency tree for a given project in Common Lisp?

I've tried using `(ql-dist:dependency-tree "my-project")` which errors (`(ql-dist:find-system "my-project")` returns `nil` whether my system is loaded or not), and `(slot-value (asdf/system:find-system "my-project") 'asdf/component:sideway-dependencies)` seems to return only *direct* dependencies where I'm looking for the full tree (it also seems to return conditional/implementation-specific dependencies, such as `sb-posix` and `sb-bsd-sockets`, which I'd prefer to do without).

Is there a standard one-step way of doing this, or will I need to recursively walk the output of that `sideway-dependencies` slot and filter idiosyncratically?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crack at the solution:

**Take 3 (this could probably be a its own project at this stage)**:

```
(defgeneric ->key (thing))

(defmethod ->key ((thing string))
  (intern (string-upcase thing) :keyword))

(defmethod ->key ((thing symbol))
  (if (keywordp thing)
      thing
      (intern (symbol-name thing) :keyword)))

(defgeneric dependencies-of (system))
(defmethod dependencies-of ((system symbol))
  (mapcar #'->key (slot-value (asdf/system:find-system system) 'asdf/component:sideway-dependencies)))

(defun ordered-dep-tree (dep-tree)
  (let ((res))
    (labels ((in-res? (dep-name) (member dep-name res))
             (insert-pass (remaining)
                (loop for (dep . sub-deps) in remaining
                      for unmet-sub-deps = (remove-if #'in-res? sub-deps)
                      if (null unmet-sub-deps) do (push dep res)
                      else collect (cons dep unmet-sub-deps) into next-rems
                      finally (return next-rems))))
      (loop for (dep . callers) in dep-tree for deps-of = (dependencies-of dep)
            if (null deps-of) do (push dep res)
            else collect (cons dep deps-of) into non-zeros
            finally (loop while non-zeros
                          do (setf non-zeros (insert-pass non-zeros)))))
      (reverse res)))

(defgeneric dependency-tree (system))
(defmethod dependency-tree ((system symbol))
  (let ((res (make-hash-table)))
    (labels ((rec (sys) 
               (loop with deps = (dependencies-of sys)
                  for dep in deps for dep-k = (->key dep)
                  unless (gethash dep-k res) do (rec dep)
                  do (pushnew (->key sys) (gethash dep-k res)))))
      (rec system))
     (ordered-dep-tree (alexandria:hash-table-alist res))))
```

That still doesn't filter for `sb-*`-style packages, but I figure I can do that in a separate pass. It seems to work though...

```
CL-USER> (dependency-tree :hunchentoot)

(:SB-BSD-SOCKETS :TRIVIAL-BACKTRACE :RFC2388 :SB-ROTATE-BYTE 
 :TRIVIAL-GARBAGE :TRIVIAL-FEATURES :CL-PPCRE :ALEXANDRIA :SB-POSIX 
 :CL-BASE64 :TRIVIAL-GRAY-STREAMS :USOCKET :MD5 :BABEL :FLEXI-STREAMS 
 :BORDEAUX-THREADS :CHUNGA :CFFI :CL-FAD :CL+SSL)
```

I *think* that's a list of all packages that need to be loaded before `:hunchentoot`, presented in an order they can be loaded (no package appears before all of its dependencies appear). It doesn't handle circular dependencies, but I don't think asdf does either, so...